# Эмуляция мыши в игре с прямым вводом, и резкое перемещение

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Прямой ввод:

Pyautogui мне не подходит, так как не работает с прямым вводом мыши, пытался добавлять библиотеку pydirectinput - не заметил разницы, так же не работает.

Резкоя перемещение по координатам в 3d fps играх:

И тут мне Pyautogui не помогает, он наводит чуть чуть в сторону куда указано, а не сразу(резко) к координатам, но если использовать это в обычном paint, то всё работает как надо.

ВОПРОС: есть ли способы которые могли бы решить хотя бы одну из этих проблем?

p.s я выключал все ограничения:

```
pyautogui.MINIMUM_DURATION = 0
pyautogui.MINIMUM_SLEEP = 0
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

Comment: а сколько фпс в млмент поворота ? может там сама игра лагает ?

Comment: @Интик в чём и проблема, это не должно зависить от фпс игры или чего либо. Я использую cascade для распознавания изображения в игре, и наводка зависит от фпс захвата, хотя ничего не мешает тупо наводится прямо на голову, а не по 5 - 10 пикселей к самой цели, так как я видел что на ютубе у человека в 3 фпс наводка была резкая - ровно в голову. (Игра - CS:GO (тут можно выключить прямой ввод))

Comment: читы в кс работают иначе(через инжектор длл). а движения мышки зависят от отображения от фпс

Comment: @Интик о каких читах речь идёт? Я не про читы речь введу, мне не нужно что бы был инжект, а просто эмуляция мыши.